CAShapeLayer stokeLine has a border like line when theme changes
I used CAShapeLayer to draw a line above a customized UIView. It looks perfect when draw for the first time. But when I switch theme the stoke line of the CALayer contains a border like line. I dont know why it is drawing like this?
Before it looks like this: https://i.postimg.cc/VLKY9k6K/light.jpg

After it looks like this: https://i.postimg.cc/V6ZSHWsV/Dark.png

// Code used to draw line
public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        let topCenterPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
        let topLeftPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 3)
        let bottomRightPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 3, y:  self.frame.height)

        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: topCenterPoint)
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: topLeftPoint)
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: bottomRightPoint)
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.close()
        
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBackground.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }


You are adding ANOTHER CAShapeLayer every time draw() is called. You should either draw the path, or setup a shape layer when you initialize the view and then update the layer in layoutSubviews(). As a side note, the code you posted does not produce the image(s) you posted...

Thank you, @DonMag. I have moved the line self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer) to the init method of the View, and I have also shifted the declaration of "shapeLayer" from the draw method to a property of the view. Now everything is working fine. I apologize for not including the entire view's code, but only the code related to shapeLayer.
